# I want to change my email in my profile

Tags: support, email

I input a wrong email address two weeks ago. Now I want to change my email in my profile but failed even though I put in a correct one.

Comment: Failed how? Any error messages?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to your profile, you should see a button marked "edit". Clicking that gives you a chance to change your email.

[image: edit button]